# Select elements that are hidden only due to inherited style (not due to having no text content)

Tags: jquery, css, dom

I want to filter out the elements (from a given jQuery object) that are hidden due to an explicit `display: none` on itself or due to an ancestor being hidden and not because of it happens to have no text in it at the time of selection.

For example:

```
<p id="p"></p>
```

Now, `$('#p').is(':hidden')` will be `true` because the paragraph has no text content in it and thus has no visible width or height. However, if I put some text in the p, jQuery will no longer consider it hidden. My code needs to find this kind of elements and put text in them.

Unfortunately the computed style of the element does not inherit `display: none` from ancestors, so it seems the only way to find out if something is hidden due to styling is to walk the tree up until an element with `display: none` is found:

```
jQuery.expr.filters.reallyHidden = function(elem) {
    do {
        if (jQuery.css( elem, "display" ) === "none") {
            return true;
        }
        elem = elem.parentNode;
    } while (elem);
    return false;
};
```

Is there any simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Closest I could get was `​$(':hidden​​​​​​​​').not(':empty')​​​​​.not('script')`. ;) For specifically checking `display:none`, I can't see a more optimal solution than what you have...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter out the elements you want.  This will find all elements in the body and return all that have an explicit display:none css

```
$('body').find('*').filter(function(){ 
    return $(this).css('display') == 'none';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yrc4M/

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't want to get all the hidden elements in body, (`$(':hidden')` already does that), I want to filter from a given jQuery object. I have edited the question to make that clear.